# cocos2d-X facebook integration c++

Tags: android, c++, facebook, cocos2d-x

I am a new developer to the cocos2d-X platform using c++. I am looking to integrate Facebook sdk into my game. Is the only way of doing this through, ANDROID JNI bridge. Is there any native C++ apis available. Can anyone share their experiences of cocos2d-X and facebook.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

(I assume that you use cocos2d-x 2.x)

Try EziSocial: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/news/109
If I recall correctly, it was even added to cocos recently; otherwise, follow the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/hiepnd/Screw. It's a killer Facebook SDK for cocos2d-x v3